# How long does it take an app to receive APNS push_token during first launch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I need to register anonymous user ASAP when an app launches. Also, need to send received push _token to backend, so not sure should I wait for push token and send all related info in one request, or should I split that into two separate operations. So, what is an average time for push token to receive?

Comment: What is push_token? Are you talking about device token?

Comment: Its depends on you device connectivity. If your device connected to the internet with sufficient speed, your application will immediately get the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no certain time defined to receive push notification.

If you want to register your device to backend, you can use this method in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

For complete understanding, see this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).

Comment: +1: Ray Wenderlich's site is awesome.